# AWS EMR bootstrap action python libraries are getting over written by Amazon EMR default libraries

Tags: bash, devops, amazon-emr

I am using bootstrap action file to install few python dependencies but i see they are over written with  Amazon EMR default libraries. To avoid this i am using the below script from [here](https://repost.aws/knowledge-center/emr-install-python-libraries) as bootstrap action.

```
#!/bin/bash
while true; do
NODEPROVISIONSTATE=\` sed -n '/localInstance [{]/,/[}]/{
/nodeProvisionCheckinRecord [{]/,/[}]/ {
   /status: / { p }
    /[}]/a
   }
  /[}]/a
}'  /emr/instance-controller/lib/info/job-flow-state.txt | awk ' { print \$2 }'\`
        if [ "\$NODEPROVISIONSTATE" == "SUCCESSFUL" ]; then
                     sleep 10;
                echo "Running my post provision bootstrap"
                #your code here
                #Below example lines
                #sudo python3 -m pip uninstall numpy==1.16.5 (this is default version of numpy)
                #sudo python3 -m pip install --upgrade numpy==1.20.1 (new version of numpy)
                exit;
        fi
sleep 10;
done
```

Now i am not sure the reason why NODEPROVISIONSTATE is PENDING state. I have launched one more EMR without bootstrap action file but it went SUCCESSFUL state. I am not sure where exactly i am doing the mistake.

Answer (score 0):

My bad i have miss read the last line from the documentation.

```
add this script as a bootstrap script that runs in the background and exits successfully so that cluster provisioning continues. This script continues to monitor node provisioning and upgrades the library after provisioning.
```

I have to do this to fix my issue.

Answer (score 0):

The bootstrap action script needs to run another script in background so that it can check for node-provisioning to complete, and then execute the post-launch tasks. In your bootstrap script, it is simply going to keep the cluster in bootstrapping phase until it'll eventually timeout. This article provides an example bootstrap script that you can refer to. https://omkarkulkarni.medium.com/quick-guide-to-bootstrapping-java-11-on-emr-d70f0115efe8